# the returned value in const* char type gets dereferenced immediately when it got the value

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

The following function returns a value in const char* typed.

```
productID = udev_device_get_sysattr_value(device,"idProduct");
```

However, it gets dereferenced right after getting the returned value.

This makes my system error and crashed.

How can I keep the reference with this returned value ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's not returning `NULL`?

Comment: It depends on what the function is doing.

Comment: what is *dereferencing* `const char*` used for?

Comment: @user657267, it is not. It is assigned a value but gets dereferenced almost in the same time.

Comment: @Sam I have no idea what you are trying to ask, post your complete code.

Comment: @PiotrS. the productID points to NULL.

Comment: @Sam: I mean what for you use `*productID` if `productID` is declared `const char*` ?

Comment: Post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this is unanswerable without it.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask, post complete code please.

Comment: well, i want to post a MCVE but it might does not make sense since this function depends on libudev which is not available to all types of machines.

Comment: The more I think about it, the more it becomes clear that this is a terribly presented question. The type of `productID` is not specified, the wording is ambiguous (it mentions references without saying how they come into the picture). There's vagueness around what's done to `productID` after the call and about the details of the crash. There's too little code to be able to say anything. Voting to close.

Comment: @NPE, thanks. I will pay more attention to this next time when I ask questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **dereference** means to access the data, to which pointer points.

What you probably mean is that the data gets deleted right after you get a pointer to it. 
Try `strcpy` the returned value into your productId.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: Would you mind showing me a simple snippet ?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcpy/

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `productID` is a `std::string` (or an instance of some other class).

Since `udev_device_get_sysattr_value()` can return `NULL`, this can be problematic since assigning `NULL` to a `std::string` results in undefined behaviour.

To fix this, assign the function's return value to a `const char*` variable and check for `NULL` before doing anything else with it.

Comment: Nope, productID is a const char* type variable.
But checking for NULL is probably a workaround to this issue.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo.

Comment: const char* is the one I was trying to type. sorry to this.

Comment: @NPE, yes, i just edited my comment and make it correct.

Comment: @Sam: Anyway, if `productID` is `const char*`, then assigning to it won't result in the pointer being dereferenced. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: thanks. then it points to NULL after having the correct value immediately.

Comment: @Sam Variables don't suddenly change. If it changes, it's because you're doing something with it.